# PHP error when trying to get script in a loop

Tags: php, domxpath

I'm using wordpress with the plugin Advanced custom fields.

I want to get some inner text from some of my website's
if i do it with this php script it works

```
$some_link = 'http://tweakers.net/';
$tagName = 'span';
$attrName = 'class';
$attrValue = 'subtitle';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($some_link);

$html = getTags( $dom, $tagName, $attrName, $attrValue );
echo $html;

function getTags( $dom, $tagName, $attrName, $attrValue ){
    $html = '';
    $domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $newDom = new DOMDocument;
    $newDom->formatOutput = true;

   $filtered = $domxpath->query("//$tagName" . '[@' . $attrName . "='$attrValue']");
   // $filtered =  $domxpath->query('//div[@class="className"]');
   // '//' when you don't know 'absolute' path

  // since above returns DomNodeList Object
  // I use following routine to convert it to string(html); copied it from someone's post in this site. Thank you.
    $i = 0;
    while( $myItem = $filtered->item($i++) ){
        $node = $newDom->importNode( $myItem, true );    // import node
        $newDom->appendChild($node);                    // append node
    }
    $html = $newDom->saveHTML();
    return $html;
}
```

Only i want to do it in a loop so i can get more from diverent site's

when i put the code like this :

```
$rows = get_field('get_attribute');
if($rows)
{
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
       THE SAME AS ABOVE PHP CODE
    }           
}
```

Then i get this error

```
  Fatal error: Call to undefined function getTags()
```

when i put the function above the

```
        $html = getTags( $dom, $tagName, $attrName, $attrValue );
        echo $html;
```

i get the error

```
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getTags()
```

when i put it all up above i get nothing no error its just blank

i hope someone can help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

found it this is the proper way

```
$rows = get_field('get_attribute');
if($rows)
{
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $some_link = $row['url'];
        $tagName = $row['attribute'];
        $attrName = $row['attribute_name'];
        $attrValue = $row['attribute_value'];

        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        @$dom->loadHTMLFile($some_link);

        $html = getTags( $dom, $tagName, $attrName, $attrValue );
        echo $html;

    }           
}

        function getTags( $dom, $tagName, $attrName, $attrValue ){
            $html = '';
            $domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
            $newDom = new DOMDocument;
            $newDom->formatOutput = true;

           $filtered = $domxpath->query("//$tagName" . '[@' . $attrName . "='$attrValue']");
           // $filtered =  $domxpath->query('//div[@class="className"]');
           // '//' when you don't know 'absolute' path

          // since above returns DomNodeList Object
          // I use following routine to convert it to string(html); copied it from someone's post in this site. Thank you.
            $i = 0;
            while( $myItem = $filtered->item($i++) ){
                $node = $newDom->importNode( $myItem, true );    // import node
                $newDom->appendChild($node);                    // append node
            }
            $html = $newDom->saveHTML();
            return $html;
        }
```